# Increment cell value by constant number using mouse click on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mouseevent

I would like to use mouse clicks as a way of incrementing or substracting values from cells on Gsheets
I came across the following piece of code for excel which works perfectly but I need the equivalent code for Google sheets if possible. Thank you for your help in advance!

````
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)


    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target = Target - 0.05
    End If


End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)


    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target = Target + 0.05
    End If


End Sub ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a button with "Insert - Drawing", and apply this script:

```
function increment() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
  var value = range.getValue()
  
  if(value == ""){value = 1}
  else if(typeof(value)!="number"){SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("It's not a number");}
  else(value++)
  range.setValue(value)
}
```

If the selected cell is empty, it will asign 1; if it is text, it will return a prompt; and if it's a number will add 1

[image]